# Trying to change alt + Tab hot key to a mouse macro and having trouble

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Im trying to add my Mouse 4 button to the task changing hotkey for windows but having trouble finding how to do so.

Ended up using Auto Hot Key

```
XButton1 & XButton2::AltTab
return.
```

Comment: So are you trying to set a key to run a macro (as you did with AutoHotKey OR reassign a mouse button to a Hot Key? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-reassign-mouse-buttons-8012f6b3-3b63-fd3f-39f0-30fde318db09 describes using their Mouse and Keyboard software.

Comment: I'm using a Levkey Ergonomic Mouse and Yes I was trying to run a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently *(June 2021)* Windows 10 doesn't offer anything other then Left-Right button switching.

I checked [Levkey.store,](https://lekvey.store/) but apparently they offer no drivers or software specific to their mice so you are left to find third party software that will work or continue to use AutoHotKey's [hotkey definitions.](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

[X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) is the top recommended 3rd party software for custom mouse and trackball configuration from numerous tech websites.

[realityripple.com](https://realityripple.com/Software/Applications/) has *Mouse Manager* and *Advanced Mouse Manager* which are specific too customizing `button4` and `button5`

Comment: @TheGreen Lightbulb Could you leave some feedback on other software you used? It could be useful for others to know.

Comment: @TheGreen Lightbulb This intriques me, so I will bookmark this, and research how to set buttons without 3rd party software.

Comment: @TheGreen Lightbulb added link.